# Unable to allocate 60.0 GiB for an array with shape.. Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm using [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-neural-machine-translation-system-keras) tutorial to develop Neural Translation System using Keras in Python.
I've successfully managed to train and test my neural network with a dataset that contains 30k phrases.
The problem is if I go beyond 30k phrases, my computer runs out of memory (I have 32 RAM).
I Probably need to generate smaller datasets and retrain the network. But if I do it, then the previous dataset the neural network trained about is forgotten, if I try to test the network after training it on a different dataset it shows differents result like it forgat what it learned.

How can this problem be solved?
All the code that I am using is in the tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

use a MySQL database to store your dataset or slice it to blocks before storing it

Comment: What do you mean?
The dataset is already stored in a .txt file the problem is when I load it all at once, my computer rans out of memory

Comment: ofc it will run out of memory, before storing the dataset you should slice it then store it, like every 100mb store it in a different file or using a MySQL database would make it easy

Comment: But if I store the dataset in a MySQL database and then load it I think it will take the same memory, or not?

Comment: No, sql databases are different try mongoDB its used by facebook https://www.simform.com/mongodb-vs-mysql-databases/

Comment: Can I use SQLite DB?